# PostgreSQL 11: multiple key-value pairs with json_object_agg()

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, group-by

Using PostgreSQL 11, the aggregate function `json_object_agg()` creates a JSON object from key and value, like the current uptime:

```
# SELECT json_object_agg('uptime', date_trunc('second',
  current_timestamp - pg_postmaster_start_time()));
```

This outputs the JSON object:

```
{ "uptime" : "00:45:55" }
```

How can I merge multiple key-value pairs into one single object? For instance, how to add the PostgreSQL version string to the object?

```
# SELECT json_object_agg('version', version());
```

The desired result may look like:

```
{
    "uptime": "00:60:01",
    "version": "PostgreSQL 11.7"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_object_agg is for *aggregating*, that is summarizing an arbitrary number of rows.

You can use it for your purpose by making it look like the data is coming in as multiple rows with 2 columns each.  You can use a VALUES list for this purpose.

```
select jsonb_object_agg(key,val) from (
values 
    ('uptime',date_trunc('second', current_timestamp - pg_postmaster_start_time())::text),
    ('version',version())
) foo(key,val);
```

Using json(b)_build_object with 4 arguments and one implicit/dummy row is probably more natural for the exact case you give.  That might be all you want to do at the moment, but if you are working with JSON you should know how json(b)_object_agg works even if it is not what you need right now.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `json_build_object()` to generate a JSON object for key/value pairs.

```
json_object_agg(
    json_build_object(
        'uptime', date_trunc('second', current_timestamp - pg_postmaster_start_time()),
        'version', version()
    )
)
```

Comment: The following query works: `SELECT json_build_object('uptime', date_trunc('second', current_timestamp - pg_postmaster_start_time()), 'version', version())`. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of an aggregated query, example:

```
select point_id, json_agg(
    json_build_object(
        'lat', lat,
        'lng', lon
        ))
from raw
group by point_id;
```

Result:

```
1,"[{"lat": 66.316917131, "lng": 65.308411872}, {"lat": 66.361430767, "lng": 65.218795224}]"
2,"[{"lat": 53.557419623, "lng": 102.39525849}, {"lat": 53.626151788, "lng": 102.529763433}]"
3,"[{"lat": 56.452206128, "lng": 100.731635684}, {"lat": 56.520627931, "lng": 100.771568911}]"
```